# Convert SHORT to TCHAR?

Tags: c++, winapi, short, tchar

I am coding a Win32 Program,and I want to text out the X pos and Y pos to the Screen, and I want to know how to convert  SHORT  to TCHAR. don't use the 
atoi or itoa function.

This is a toy program, and I want to text out the position of the mouse, but I donnot konw how to convert short to TCHAR.

[image]

Comment: use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) or its wide char sibling, don't use `TCHAR` type. `TCHAR` and friends were a Microsoft technology in support of Windows 9x. Are you targeting Windows 9x?

Comment: When you say "TCHAR", do you mean "a single TCHAR (which is an alias for *either* `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on how you compile your code), or do you mean "an array of TCHAR" which, again, is either an array of `char` or of `wchar_t`, in other words, a C-style string.

Comment: Um, you are leaking the DC. Also, you are drawing outside the paint cycle, which will cause repaint corruption.

Comment: Yes, I am leaking the DC, but I want to know why drawing ouside the paint cycle can cause repaint corruption. and how the textout function works.

Comment: If you draw in WM_MOUSEMOVE and your entire window ends up being redrawn with a WM_PAINT, you will lose your text display at 100,100. This is because a WM_ERASEBKGND will cause your entire screen to be erased. You basically need to store the x,y coordinates and paint the same thing in the WM_PAINT handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to convert a unsigned int to a string. You can use std::to_wstring if TCHAR is defined as a WCHAR:

```
short x = 123;    
std::wstring s = std::to_wstring(x);
```

Then convert `s.c_str()` to a `TCHAR*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss("");
ss << nX << " " << nY;

TextOut(GetDC(hWnd), 100, 100, reinterpret_cast<TCHAR *>(ss.str().c_str()), ss.str().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHORT myVal;
TCHAR buf[32]; // 32 is big enough to contain a 16-bit int as a string

_stprintf_s(buf,ARRAYSIZE(buf),"%hd",myVal);
// now buf contains the text as a TCHAR
```